# Redirect to dashboard if user is loggedin in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = "layouts.dashboard";
public function __construct(){

//$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
$this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getIndex')));

}
public function getIndex(){
     $this->layout->content= View::make('dashboard.index');
}



}
```

> Above given code is my dashboardController. It is ok when i login and it redirects to dashboard. When the user is in dashboard, it means the user is authenticated. Now in the url bar, i hits the url of login. in my case it is

```
http://localhost:8000/users/login
```

> now it redirects to login even the user is logged in. Now when i want to know how we can redirect to dashboard authomatically if the user is logged in.
>   I am new to laravel 4.2. I hope you will guide me. Im lost in this section

Comment: I would recommend to directly jump to laravel 5 and take a look on Middleware it is just wow https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: You have not provided routes and views files however if you have created that filter just apply it on your login that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put this into your `getIndex()` function:

```
if(Session::has('login_parameters')) return Redirect::to('foo/dashboard');
```

I use this code in Laravel 3, hopefully it works in laravel 4.2 as well.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Would you consider to mark this answer as correctly if it works for you?